# how do I writing function for this code

Tags: c, loops, output

I'm trying to write a function or method for the code. I'm really lost at how to come with the loop that print out the number born and number died in the output below.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char grid[10][10];

// Moved this function here
int occ(int x, int y) {
    int i, j, count;
    char gridCopy[10][10];


// You probably are going to do this often in the future
// Make a function for it instead of having the same code often
void printGrid() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: the code will be more efficient if each cell is `0` or `1`, not `'*'`, since when adding neighbours you can sum the cell values directly. Otherwise you'll have clumsy tests for `'*'`, done 8 times per cell on each pass, whereas you only actually need the `'*'` once per cell in each generation's display.

Comment: To expand on what @WeatherVane said: internally, keep track of the cells using `0` & `1`, but print things out as `-` an `*`

Comment: Keep separate **form** from **function**. That way you can easilly re-use the computational parts with a wonderful new GUI interface.

Comment: Hey guys can you please write a simple function, like a basic structure of the method I want for me? I'm really lost

Comment: There is a basic code structure here http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/150926-conway%27s-game-life.html but whether it works or is complete, is for you to explore.

Comment: Oh thanks, I meant part of the code that print out Generation #2 Number born = 2 Number died = 0. I want a loop or count to check that, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `gridCopy` in `occ` function.
Please remember that array is transposed. When you access element (x,y) you need to use `grid[y][x]`

Below is the working code with function `generateNext()` which generates next state for whole `grid` array. This is place where you need `girdCopy`. Results are exactly the same as in your example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char grid[10][10];
int  born,died,generation;

// Moved this function here
int occ(int x, int y) {
    int  count;
    int  xm1,xp1,ym1,yp1;

    xm1=x-1;xp1=x+1;ym1=y-1;yp1=y+1;
    if (xm1<0) // handle boundary cases - wrap around
        xm1=9;
    if (ym1<0)
        ym1=9;
    if (xp1>9)
        xp1=0;
    if (yp1>9)
        yp1=0;

    // Checking on the value of the neighboring cells
    count = 0;
    if (grid[ym1][x] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[ym1][xp1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[y][xp1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[yp1][xp1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[yp1][x] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[yp1][xm1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[y][xm1] == '*')
        count++;
    if (grid[ym1][xm1] == '*')
        count++;

    return count;
}

void generateNext()
{
    int x,y;
    char gridCopy[10][10];

    born=0;died=0;
    generation++;

    for (y=0; y<10; y++) {
        for (x=0; x<10; x++) {
            gridCopy[y][x]=grid[y][x];
        }
    }

    for (y=0; y<10; y++) {
        for (x=0; x<10; x++) {
            if (grid[y][x]=='*' && occ(x,y)<2)
                {gridCopy[y][x]='-';died++;}
            if (grid[y][x]=='*' && occ(x,y)>3)
                {gridCopy[y][x]='-';died++;}
            if (grid[y][x]=='-' && occ(x,y)==3)
                {gridCopy[y][x]='*';born++;}
        }
    }

    for (y=0; y<10; y++) {
        for (x=0; x<10; x++) {
            grid[y][x]=gridCopy[y][x];
        }
    }
}

// You probably are going to do this often in the future
// Make a function for it instead of having the same code often
void printGrid() {
    int x, y;
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            printf("%c", grid[y][x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int x, y, answ;

    // Setting entire grid to '-'
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            grid[y][x] = '-'; // No need for a variable, just use '-' directly

    // Printing out grid
    printf("This is the original array\n");
    printGrid();

    // Setting initial state
    grid[5][4] = '*'; // No need for a variable, just use '*' directly
    grid[5][5] = '*'; 
    grid[5][6] = '*'; 
    grid[4][4] = '*'; grid[3][4] = '*';
    grid[4][6] = '*'; grid[3][6] = '*';

    // Printing out grid
    printf("This is the new array\n");
    printGrid();

    //printf("The number of neighbors is: %d\n", occ(3, 3));

    generation=0;
    answ=1;

    while(answ)
    {
        generateNext();
        printf("\n\nGeneration number %d",generation);
        printf("\nBorn=%d,Died=%d\n",born,died);
        printGrid();
        printf("\nPrint next generation-1,Exit-0:");
        scanf("%d",&answ);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting is similar to what you have to do to print or copy the whole grid: you use the same loop(s), but at each cell, add to the appropriate counter depending on what is in it.

Alternatively, if keep counts of the number of dead and live cells, you can update those as you update the grid: if a cell changes, update the counters appropriately if the cell becomes alive or becomes dead.  This can also be used if you need to report how many were born & how many died each turn.

Comment: Hey Scott you want help me here, I keep getting lost on how to wrting the loops, want give me basic code structure?

Comment: You already have 3 examples in the code that you posted: copying `grid` to `gridCopy` in `occ()`; `printGrid()`; and the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I meant part of the code that print out Generation #2
Number born = 2     Number died = 0

Comment: that should be a loop right, I don't have that in my code, is that what you mean?